# How to build a .NET Windows library using a COM reference, that could target either .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net

**Context**

Using an API delivered as a COM reference, the goal is to build Windows-only applications targeting either *.NET Framework 4.8* or *.NET 6*.

A library of helper methods around the API will be written and be reused across projects.

**Question**

What would be the best way to build this library, so that it could be used either in a *.NET Framework 4.8* project or in a *.NET 6* project?

So far here are the options I thought about:

- Using *.NET Standard*: Impossible since it is not possible to reference a COM dll in a *.NET Standard* project. The reason is that a *.NET Standard* library should warrant that it could run on every compatible target, which includes non-Windows target, on which COM makes no sense. Or am I wrong?
- The obvious one: Making two libraries, one targeting *.NET Framework 4.8* and the other *.NET 6*. Copy/Paste code from one to the other. A little bit nasty, but it works.
- A variation: Making two libraries, again, but this time having the second library simply reference the source files of the first one, using *Visual Studio* feature `Add as Link`. You still need to perform the adding operation in the second project every time you create a new file in the first one, so it is not fully automated.
- Another variation: Making two libraries, one targeting *.NET Framework 4.8* and the other *.NET 6*. But this time have a script (or a service, etc...) automatically mirror the source files from one project to the other.

Is there any better way to achieve this? Did I miss something?

Comment: I'd avoid leading a question with "what is the best", because it's typically indicative of a question that requires an opinion answer, not a fact based one

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I edited the title.

Comment: You are right about the .NET standard option because COM is indeed bound to windows. It is possible to target multiple frameworks with one library. Just  change `TargetFramework` in `TargetFrameworks` and use a semicolon separated list in your csproj file. for example: `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;netframework4.8</TargetFramework>` but that is also tricky because if underlying libraries don't support both options you still will get issues.

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen: it seems a good idea, I'll check that. I guess that your example should rather have been: `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows;netframework4.8</TargetFramework>`?

Comment: @LaurentGabiot it depends on what you want. But if you only want to support .NET 6.0 (for windows) and .NET Framework 4.8 then that would suffice. But still the issue of libraries which do not support either one of the target frameworks exists.  Check this for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file

Comment: @LaurentGabiot I am currently facing the same issue (IBM MQ uses .NET Framework 4.6.x for its library and I want to use .NET Standard.) So in my case I could use a REST service which targets .NET framework 4.6 and a .NET standard client library which consumes the REST service.

Comment: We're living in the age of agile, deciding to create a branch in source control to work on the .NETCore build should be a heck-why-not decision.  Don't overlook that .NET5 and 6 have pretty decent support for legacy .NETFramework targeted libraries, as long as they use BCL types.  Add a project reference to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of projects that use `COMReference`.  For multi-targeting different frameworks for these projects, I use the following, in my csproj file:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net472;net5.0-windows;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```

net472, as well as, net48 is supposedly equivalent with netstandard2.0.

if going through nuget, nuget will attempt to match the correct dll out of the multi-pack bundle with the corresponding framework of the host application.

**Edit:**

Surprisingly, netstandard2.0 Supports `COMReference` property.  Perhaps Net Core 3.1 as well.  From NET5.0 onwards, at least, the `COMReference` property is not supported (You would need to use NET?.0-windows).

So my revised TargetFrameworks is:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net472;net5.0-windows;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```